# Clipping a raster by a polygon layer: Error "Cutline is not valid after transformation"

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, error, self-intersection

I have a raster layer (3 cm x 3 cm) and a vector layer with polygons and when I try to clip the raster by the polygon layer to have just the bare earth/ground regions left over, so I can interpolate them afterwards, I always get the error below:

```
Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 571.37754947319627 322.188317745924 
ERROR 1: Cutline is not valid after transformation
```

The polygon layer was derived from the raster layer.

I am working with QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Try buffering the vector layer with a buffer size of 0. Sounds weird, but helps sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but maybe I didn't really get it: If I buffer a layer with a buffer size of 0 in the distance field, shouldn't I get an empty layer?

Comment: No. The buffer adds to the input geometry. In this case, it adds nothing but might clean up some errors.

Comment: So when I set the Fixed Distance Buffer with a distance of 0.0, it creates a new layer with no visuable data.... this is probably not the expected result?

Comment: It may mean that the source geometry has such problem with the topology that buffer operation fails.

Comment: What version are you using? I had the same error as you using qgis 2.14 but it works using qgis 2.10. No idea why...

Comment: @ B_Dabbler: It really worked! Thx!